# Activate global menu for Eclipse Luna 4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Eclipse Luna 4.4 on my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit machine. I want to change the local menu of Eclipse IDE to global menu. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check how your [Ubuntu settings are set](https://askubuntu.com/a/426298/5470)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ouZDsaB.png]

Select "in top bar" if you want the ["global menu" instead of the LIM (Locally Integrated Menu")](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2099903/ubuntus-ditching-unitys-global-menu-returning-to-in-app-menus.html)

Note that all menus won't show up: see [issue 419830](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419830#c12), which references [bug 1208019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-gtk-module/+bug/1208019): only `gtk+3.0 - 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2` display most of those menus.

Comment: It shows "In the menu bar" instead of "In top bar" option. And I have selected "In the menu bar" but still the eclipse menu doesn't show up as global menu but as LIM.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu fully updated with the latest packages? I suppose Eclipse menu would display in the menu bar if you were to put the Elcipse in full screen?

Comment: Yes, my Ubuntu is fully updated and also I use Eclipse in full-screen mode. Still, the menus don't appear as global.

Comment: @VonC yes, and I am facing the same issue.